# What does "et ah" mean in text citations?

Tags: meaning

I cannot find an explanation for the use of "et ah".
For example: "Davies et ah, 2015".

Many thanks,
Catherine

Comment: It is [*et al.*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/et-al.?q=et+al.), not *et ah*. which means ***And others (used especially in referring to academic books or articles that have more than one author)***

Comment: We thought that it may have been a typo, but have found instances of both in academic texts and wanted to double check.

Comment: There are so many hits in [Google](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA&gws_rd=cr#q=%22et+ah%22). But I still believe it is a typo. [Et al](https://www.google.com/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=s45BVoWaOIrN8gf1lpygCA&gws_rd=cr#q=%22et+al%22), huge difference in their hit numbers.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it looks for meaning in a typographical error.

Comment: I only checked one, and it's a scanning error for "et al."  Unless you've got a context where "et al." wouldn't be apt, it's just a typo.

Comment: When *at al* is written with full stops and followed by a comma, google and other systems that read from pdfs often pick up the [al.,] as an [ah]. It's something to do with how the pdf or other file is 'read' by the software. So for example ...

Comment: ...  if you look at these [google results](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1GGGE_en-gbGB422GB422&q=Seismicity+Patterns%2C+their+Statistical+Significance+and+Physical+Meaning+%22et+ah%22&oq=Seismicity+Patterns%2C+their+Statistical+Significance+and+Physical+Meaning+%22et+ah%22&gs_l=serp.3..30i10.5119.7947.0.8511.8.8.0.0.0.0.144.806.3j4.7.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..4.4.485.b_faNrWjlDo) you'll see lots of seeming instances of *et ah*, but when you click on the actual examples, you'll see that it's actually *et al., blah blah*)

Answer (score 1):

I believe the correct phrase is "et al." which is short for the Latin "et alius", meaning "and others". It is used often in citations, especially in lists of people. Its purpose is to shorten what could be a very long list by leaving out the less important contributors, while still giving them credit.